I have a 'succeeded' media_id. But the Pinterest API tells me "The media_id you are trying to use has not been uploaded"
I'm trying to upload a video to pinterest.
The following code returns an object as expected:
      const checkUploadStatusRes = await fetch(
        `https://api.pinterest.com/v5/media/${registerMediaUploadResponse.media_id}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${input.accessToken}`,
          },
        },
      );

i.e., I have an object as follows:
{
    "media_id": "12345",
    "media_type": "video",
    "status": "succeeded"
}

However, when I try to create the pin, I receive the following error:
{"code":1,"message":"The media_id you are trying to use has not been uploaded.","details":{"method":17,"param_name":"media_id"}}
However, my media has a status of succeeded? That means it has been successfully uploaded?
The media_source in my POST request to create a pin is:
media_source: {
    source_type: "video_id",
    cover_image_url: input.imageUrls[0],
    media_id: mediaId,
}

I can't see anything that I'm doing wrong? (The post request has correct authentication headers set -- I've just omitted them here for brevity)

Did you figure this out?
